# hibernate is not able to make the connection to database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to build a new web site but I don't know why I get this error (I test it using JUnit). I tried another project but I got the same error again:
I update stack trace with the other error any body can help me ??? its near the 5 day that i have this problem and have no idea how to fix it

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:613)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.add(Unknown Source)
    at Hpk.onlineShopping_backend.test.categotyTest.testAddCategory(categotyTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:609)
    ... 33 more
```

hibernate config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"Hpk.onlineShopping_backend.dto"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

// Change the below based on the DBMS you choose
private final static String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/onlineshopping";
private final static String DATABASE_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
private final static String DATABASE_DIALECT = "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect";
private final static String DATABASE_USERNAME = "sa";
private final static String DATABASE_PASSWORD = "";

// dataSource bean will be available
@Bean("dataSource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {

    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    // Providing the database connection information
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DATABASE_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(DATABASE_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);


    return dataSource;

}

// sessionFactory bean will be available

@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

    builder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    builder.scanPackages("Hpk.onlineShopping_backend.dto");

    return builder.buildSessionFactory();

}



// All the hibernate properties will be returned in this method 
private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

    Properties properties = new Properties();


    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", DATABASE_DIALECT);      
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");

    //properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");


    return properties;
}

// transactionManager bean
@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

DTO class:

```
package Hpk.onlineShopping_backend.dto;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
public class Category {
/*
 * private field
 * 
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String name;
private String discription;
@Column(name="image_url")
private String imgUrl;
@Column(name="is_active")
private boolean active = true;

/*
 * constructor
 * 
 */
public Category(int id, String name, String discription, String imgUrl, boolean active) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.discription = discription;
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    this.active = active;
}

public Category() {


}

/*
 * setter and getter
 * 
 */
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDiscription() {
    return discription;
}

public void setDiscription(String discription) {
    this.discription = discription;
}

public String getImgUrl() {
    return imgUrl;
}

public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
 }
```

DAO class:

```
package Hpk.onlineShopping_backend.daoImple;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import Hpk.onlineShopping_backend.dao.CategoryDAO;
import Hpk.onlineShopping_backend.dto.Category;

@Repository("categoryDAO")
public class CategoryDAOImpl implements CategoryDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private static List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

static {
    // first category
    Category category = new Category();


    categories.add(category);
    // second category
    category = new Category(2, "moblie", "discriptoin for mobile", "cat_2.png", true);
    categories.add(category);
    // third category
    category = new Category(3, "labtop", "discriptoin for labtop", "cat_3.png", true);
    categories.add(category);
}

public List<Category> list() {

    return categories;
}
public Category get(int id) {
    for (Category category : categories) {
        if (category.getId() == id)
            return category;
    }
    return null;
}
@Transactional
public boolean add(Category category) {
try {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(category);
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

test class:

```
package Hpk.onlineShopping_backend.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import  org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import Hpk.onlineShopping_backend.dao.CategoryDAO;
import Hpk.onlineShopping_backend.dto.Category;

public class categotyTest {
private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;
private static CategoryDAO categoryDAO;
private Category category;


@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.scan("Hpk.onlineShopping_backend");
    context.refresh();
    categoryDAO = (CategoryDAO) context.getBean("categoryDAO");
}

@Test
public void testAddCategory() {
    category = new Category();
    category.setId(2);
    category.setName("television");
    category.setDiscription("discriptoin for tv");
    category.setImgUrl("cat_1.png");
    assertEquals( true,categoryDAO.add(category));
}
```

Comment: Transaction marked for rollback sounds more like an SQL error than a connection error.

Comment: Please try to update with the sql produced by your code. Try this with log4j:

Comment: log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
# basic log level for all messages
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info

# SQL statements and parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace

Answer (score 0):

noRollbackFor should not be used for database exceptions as database and hibernate session may go out of sync. This attribute should be used for business logic like continuing with second service even if first service has rollbacked.

Comment: remove "noRollbackFor = Exception.class". You can keep Transactional annotation.

Comment: There isn't any SQL error in your code. Query has executed properly and this error has occured at the time of committing the transaction.